# Disable (but still allow) scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm looking to recreate the scrolling effect on this site: misfitwearables.com. So far, my approach has been to disable user scrolling, but still detect the scroll direction to allow jQuery to control how the page scrolls. The thing is that it works (yay!) .. but it only works on the first scroll. After the first scroll, it stops responding. How can I get it to listen/respond on every scroll?

```
$(this).bind( 'mousewheel', function ( e ) {
 if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
    // scroll down
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: (+50) }, 900, "easeInOutQuart" );
 } else {
    // scroll up
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: (-50) }, 900, "easeInOutQuart" );
 }
 return false;
 });
```

Comment: Not sure to be honest. It's placed within $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: $(this) is the input no?

Answer (score 1):

The animating property value is incorrect, should be `"+=50"` and `"-=50"`:

```
$(this).bind( 'mousewheel', function ( e ) {
 if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
    // scroll down
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "+=50" }, 900, "easeInOutQuart" );
 } else {
    // scroll up
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "-=50" }, 900, "easeInOutQuart" );
 }
 return false;
});
```

It was only working once because you were always passing `50` and `-50` as the value.

Here's a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/6XHeA/1/)**, I also added a check to perform only one animation per scroll event